# How to force apps to use different language instead of system language?

Tags: languages

I am a Czech, however i like english language much more so i like to have most of apps in english(besides very crappy translations). Is here any way how to set language pre-app instead of globally ? I'm sure there is no built-in way, how to do this. I'm not asking for tutorial for something what does not exist, but what i want (and I'm sure it exists because of creativity of humans) is any kind of hack or workaround how to set language pre-app.

Phone Details :

---

model : Lenovo A7000
android : 5.0.0 - ROOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time but I found solution. As I mentioned in original question, I was asking for hacky workaround and , well, what I found is very hacky.

step 1 : Have a root, the root is power. You need to have something to "flash" files to system from .zip. Clockwork recovery mod is more than sufficient. Alternatively, you can use computer with ADB and flashing tools.

step 2 : Xposed. Now we getting to core of it, literally. Xposed is framework, core for so called "Modules" With its help you can modify your android down to last variable. Great tool by itself.

step 3 : Module "App Settings". Hell yeah, now we are getting to it. Besides many ways how you can screw up your application there is field called "Locale" where you can set pre-app based language.

.... and when you are on it, you can install GravityBox too. Don't ask for what is used but you can thanks me later.